# Using the Keyboard Library how do you use a combo of keys in .is_pressed?

Tags: python, keyboard

Example of what I would like to do:

```
if keyboard.is_pressed("Shift+Q"):
```

Does anyone know how you would do something like what I showed above?

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
import keyboard
def foo():
    print('foo')
keyboard.add_hotkey('shift+q', foo)
keyboard.wait('esc')
```

Pressing Shift+Q will print foo, and pressing Escape will end.

You can also test `keyboard.is_pressed('shift+q')` in a loop if you insist.

Answer (score 0):

The keyboard module has a feature called hotkey for this. `keyboard.add_hotkey("Shift+Q")`. This should work.